$\infty$-groupoid with initial (or terminal) object is contractible.
I am currently learning about $\infty$-categories and we were asked to prove the following:
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an $\infty$-groupoid (i.e. an Kan complex) with an initial object. Show that $\mathcal{C}$ is contractible as an anima (i.e. an object in the $\infty$-category given by taking the simplicial nerve of the subcategory of Kan complexes in simplicial sets).
However I have no real idea how to start or do this. From what we have seen in the course I think the two strategies I could try is either showing that there is an equivalence $\text{Map}_{\mathcal{A}n}(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D})\to *$ for all $\mathcal{D}\in \mathcal{A}n$ or show that the geometric realization of $\mathcal{C}$ is contractible. To me the second one looks more promising since from the assumption I get information about $\text{Map}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y)$ being contractible. With this I could for example easily conclude that the 1-skelton of $|\mathcal{C}|$ is contractible but I am not sure about the higher skeleta and feel like there is a connection I am missing.

Cf. Kerodon Tag 02HM.

I think 02HJ is closer to what OP is asking for.

@NaïmFavier Indeed; however the proof presented there isn't really accessible to OP's course material (the respective course I also happen to be taking). When I wrote the comment above I thought that one should be able to mount a different argument based on that tag, but now I've sufficiently confused myself to doubt it...

@BenSteffan Is this Jack Davies' course on stable homotopy theory?

@DaniëlApol It is indeed :)

@BenSteffan Nice, I already heard he would cover $\infty$-categories. Back in my days (two years ago with Prof. Schwede) we worked with cofibration categories, but I think Jack's approach will after the initial investment pay off when actually working with spectra.

I will give three possible approaches.
For an elementary model-dependent argument: if $K$ is a Kan complex and $x\in K$, then we can define $K_{x/}$ as the fiber at $x$ of the map $\mathrm{ev}_0\colon\underline{\mathrm{sSet}}(\Delta^1,K)\to K$ which evaluates at the initial vertex. This comes with a map $K_{x/}\to \underline{\mathrm{sSet}}(\Delta^1,K)\xrightarrow{\mathrm{ev}_1}K$, whose fiber at $y\in K$ is the mapping Kan complex $K(x,y)$ (that is, it is one of the strict models for the mapping anima in the $\infty$-groupoid underlying $K$). The map $K_{x/}\to K$ is a Kan fibration: we can check from the definitions that solving a lifting problem
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Lambda^n_k @>>> K_{x/}\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\Delta^n @>>> K
\end{CD}
$$
is equivalent to finding a lift
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Lambda^n_k\times\Delta^1\bigsqcup_{\Lambda^n_k\times\partial\Delta^1}\Delta^n\times\partial\Delta^1 @>>> K\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\Delta^n\times\Delta^1 @>>> *
\end{CD}
$$
where the map $\Delta^n\times\partial\Delta^1\to K$ sends $\Delta^n\times\{0\}$ to the degeneracy on $x$ acts on $\Delta^n\times\{1\}$ the same way our original map $\Delta^n\to K$ did. The latter lifting diagram is solvable as the left-hand map is a Kan trivial cofibration and $K$ is a Kan complex.
Now, since $K$ is a Kan complex, the map $\mathrm{ev}_0\colon\underline{\mathrm{sSet}}(\Delta^1,K)\to K$ is a trivial Kan fibration (this follows from the fact that $\underline{\mathrm{sSet}}(\Delta^1,-)$ is a right adjoint and lifting calculus). Fibers of trivial Kan fibrations are contractible Kan complexes, and hence $K_{x/}$ is a contractible Kan complex for any $x$.
If $x$ is initial in $K$, this implies that all the fibers of the Kan fibration $K_{x/}\to K$ are contractible Kan complexes. This forces $K_{x/}\to K$ to be a trivial Kan fibration, and since we just saw that $K_{x/}$ is contractible, so is $K$.

For a cooler $\infty$-categorical approach: given an anima $K$, an object $x\in K$ is initial iff the forgetful functor $K_{x/}\to K$ is an equivalence of anima (as $K_{x/}\to K$ is the left fibration classifying the mapping anima functor $K(x,-)\colon K\to\mathrm{An}$ and the identity functor $K\to K$ classifies the trivial anima functor $\mathrm{const}_*\colon K\to\mathrm{An}, y\mapsto *$). We have via adjunction a chain of equivalences
$$
\mathrm{An}(L,K_{x/})\simeq\mathrm{Cat}_{\infty,*}(([0]\star L, 0), (K,x))\simeq*
$$
for any other anima $L$, where the last equivalence follows from the fact that $[0]\star L$ is weakly contractible relative to $0\in[0]\subseteq[0]\star L$ and the fact that $(K,x)$ is a pointed anima. As such, we conclude by Yoneda that $K$ is contractible if it has an initial object.

Finally, for another elementary model-dependent approach: it suffices to show that all simplicial homotopy groups of a Kan complex $K$ with initial object $x$ are $0$. Since $x$ is initial it is easy to see that $K$ is connected, so it suffices to show that $\pi_n(K,x)=0$ for all $n\geq 1$. Proving that any element of $\pi_n(K,x)$ is equal to the trivial element in that group is (after a bit of rewriting) equivalent to asking if all lifting problems
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Lambda^{n+1}_0\bigsqcup_{\partial\Delta^{\{1,2,\ldots,n+1\}}}\Delta^n @>{\mathrm{const}_x\sqcup\alpha}>> K\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\Delta^{n+1} @>>> *
\end{CD}
$$
with $n\geq 1$ are solvable, for arbitrary maps $\alpha\colon\Delta^n\to K$ satisfying the boundary condition that $\partial\Delta^n\to \Delta^n\xrightarrow{\alpha} K$ is constant on $x$. Depending on the model for mapping anima that you are used to, this follows immediately or after some combinatorics from the statement that a certain model for the mapping Kan complex $K(x,x)$ is contractible and hence has right lifting against all Kan cofibrations.
